# What is wrong with mysql installed through homebrew

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos, homebrew

```
Mac Version: 10.6.7
Ruby Version: 1.9.2-p180
Rails Version: 2.3.5
```

After installing mysql through brew and running rails server says

```
/!\ FAILSAFE /!\  2011-05-09 11:18:22 +0545
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:589:in `real_connect'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:589:in `connect'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:203:in `initialize'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:75:in `new'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:75:in `mysql_connection'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in `new_connection'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:245:in `checkout_new_connection'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:188:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `loop'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `block in checkout'
    /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:183:in `checkout'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:98:in `connection'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326:in `retrieve_connection'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123:in `retrieve_connection'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115:in `connection'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/hoptoad_notifier-2.4.9/lib/hoptoad_notifier/rack.rb:27:in `call'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/hoptoad_notifier-2.4.9/lib/hoptoad_notifier/user_informer.rb:12:in `call'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `block in call'
    :10:in `synchronize'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:114:in `block in call'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/reloader.rb:34:in `run'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:108:in `call'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/rack/static.rb:31:in `call'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:46:in `block in call'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:40:in `each'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:40:in `call'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@suga/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:50:in `service'
    /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
    /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
    /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Can you login to mysql at all (without using Rails) from the shell?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing the mysql gem in your stacktrace so I suspect you might not have installed it. If so then add `gem 'mysql'` (or `gem 'mysql2'` if you prefer) to your Gemfile, run `bundle install` and start your server again.

Also, double-check that you are indeed running Rails 3 as mentioned in your question. The stacktrace shows that you are running Rails 2.3. So similarly, in your Gemfile, make sure you have `gem 'rails', '3.0.0'`, then run `bundle install`, etc.

Comment: Thx for pointing out rails version. It is 2.3.5 but was 3.0.0 mistakenly

Comment: I suspect so. I installed Rails 2.3.5 very recently and it explicitly states in the installation instructions at some point that the mysql gem is not included with Rails in that version, so you have to `gem install mysql` to get MySQL working.

Comment: You should also make sure that you actually start the MYSql server.